# Java commands flash a cmd

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I already installed Java, JDK and added it to Path, but when I try to run a command (like "java -version") it just flashes a CMD but doesn't show what I want to see. This happens with every command and doesn't even let me run Java code using an IDE. There is no error message, just a CMD flashing every time I try to run something (it also happens when double click the files like "java", "javac", etc).

Answer (score 2):

How do you run these commands? Try running them from an interactive terminal window. Open it by typing `windows key + R` and then `cmd`.  Then `cd` into your directory and type your commands there. Alternatively, if your commands are in a `.bat` file … you may add a `pause` command at the end.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Tried both of these methods but they didn't work :(

Comment: What do you mean by "they didn't work"?   What happened when you tried them?

Comment: @Moravak You need to run literally the command `cmd` which should start the Command Prompt (or just click on the windows button (or press the windows key) and search for Command Prompt and run that).

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely expected as `java -version` immediately exits after printing the version. This means that if you didn't start it from cmd, PowerShell, or another interactive shell, it opens a window which disappears immediately because the program ended in a fraction of a second.

Start cmd (Command Prompt) or PowerShell (either directly or through Windows Terminal), and run your commands in that interactive shell.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. That's what I tried before and it still flashes a new cmd that closes immediately. I tried using cmd and PowerShell. Same result.

Comment: @Moravak Then please edit your question and specify the exact steps you took, because it still sounds like you're not running the command from the command prompt.